# Why is there no &&= operator in Java?

Tags: logical-operators, java

Even for the binary and `&` there is a shorthand operator `&=`.

So, why did the developers decide against something like `a &&= b` which would do a logical and assignment?

It would do the same like for example the `+=` operator (`a += b`) would do to `a = a + b`, shortening the expression.

Comment: What is that operator and in which language is it used?

Comment: @TagirValeev True, it could be a short-circuit assignment. It would of course potentially avoid only one evaluation, whereas `&&` has potential to avoid several.